# Como deletar no Realm no JavaScript

Tags: react-native, realmdb

Estou tentando deletar um item de uma lista usando o Realm, mas todos os métodos que tentei até agora foram falhos.

O último que tentei segundo algumas dicas, deveria funcionar, mas mesmo assim sem sucesso.

Veja o código no github: https://github.com/andrelinos/react-native-realmdb/blob/master/src/pages/Main/index.js

Consegui apagar toda a base usando o código abaixo:

```js
realm.write(() => {
      realm.delete(realm.objects('Repository'));
    });
```

Mas, apagar apenas um item, ainda sem sucesso. 
O código abaixo, deveria funcionar, mas simplesmente retorna erro.

```
      realm.delete(realm.objectForPrimaryKey('Repository', repository.id));
    });
```

Erro retornado:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 17):
Error: Argument to 'delete' must be a Realm object or a collection of Realm objects.
delete@[native code]
```

Desde já obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua schema está sendo declarada como uma classe:

```
export default class RepositorySchema {
  static schema = {
    name: 'Repository',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
      id: { type: 'int', indexed: true },
      login: 'string',
      name: 'string',
      fullName: 'string',
      description: 'string',
      avatarUrl: 'string',
      stars: 'int',
      forks: 'int',
      watchersCount: 'int',
    },
  };
}
```

Tente declarar sua schema apenas como um objeto:

```
export default RepositorySchema = {
  name: 'Repository',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: { type: 'int', indexed: true },
    login: 'string',
    name: 'string',
    fullName: 'string',
    description: 'string',
    avatarUrl: 'string',
    stars: 'int',
    forks: 'int',
    watchersCount: 'int',
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estava com o mesmo problema porém consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

importações:

```
import Realm from 'realm';
import getRealm from '~/services/realm';
```

código:

```
const realmDelete = () => {

  const realm = new Realm(getRealm());

  realm.write(() => {
    realm.delete(realm.objectForPrimaryKey('Repository', repository.id));
  });

}
```